# Shadow Copy With Storage Spaces?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, system-restore, volume-shadow-copy

I converted 2 of my drives to be a mirrored storage space on windows 10. I am using ReFS. This drive is d drive.

When I create a restore point the dialog that comes up does not have d drive in it.

[image]

Thus I cannot configure the shadow copy space allocation for that drive, or turn system protection on or off. I used to be able to do this when the drives were separate and NTFS.

My aim is to schedule a daily restore point using the powershell Checkpoint-Computer command. But I assume that this drive won't be included if I can't configure it in the system restore dialog?

Why is it missing? Is there some kind of issue with storage spaces or ReFS? I suspect not because my backup program is creating a snapshot of that d drive when running a backup.

I found some information about enabling drives for system restore in powershell,

[image]

But again no luck. I found others online saying that I should run powershell as administrator, which I am doing, and also to check the drive exists, and this follows,

[image]

**Update:**

I tried this command as suggested. I double checked I was using an elevated command prompt,

vssadmin add shadowstorage /for=D: /on=D: /maxsize=100GB

And this is what I get,

[image]

Looks like this is only for server versions of windows.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276093/windows-10-how-to-create-shadow-storage-on-another-drive-without-vssadmin-create

Comment: Perhaps you simply need to enable Volume Shadows on the "D" partition with elevated command such as: **1.** `vssadmin add shadowstorage /for=D: /on=D: /maxsize=100GB` to define it, then **2.** `vssadmin create shadow /for=D:` to create it? You can always change it once created such as: `vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=C: /on=C: /maxsize=50GB`... Give it a shot and look over https://ss64.com/nt/vssadmin.html when you get a chance.

Comment: This doesn't work on windows 10 as per the above. Maybe I am out of luck.

Comment: Be sure you are running the command from an elevated command prompt with run as administrator. Maybe try creating with **#2** first but be sure to change the `C:` to `D:` or whatever you need as well as the `50GB` value to whatever you need—this will accept percentage too. It should work with Windows 10 just fine. Tag me back if you find out otherwise and I will do testing later but specify what `winver` you are running. I could be wrong but tag me back as I'm gonna be busy for a few and will forget otherwise/

Comment: I don't think System Restore evaluates drives formatted as anything other than NTFS, possibly with exceptions for the System partition. What file system is your C: drive formatted as? A good test would be to add two new drives - one as NTFS and the other as ReFS.

Comment: This was working with my d drive when it was a single drive as NTFS. But since then I have made it ReFS, and added it to a storage space. Either one of those two things must have caused this. Yes I am running it as elevated command prompt. Shadow copies do work with ReFS and storage space as my backup program is creating a temporary shadow copy of that drive when backing up. This seems to be a MS imposed limitation which is not present on server versions of the OS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## 1 Create shadow storage

**1.1 The `System protection` tab in `System Properties`**

- this GUI only lists NTFS volumes, so you can't create shadow storage for ReFS volume there
- instead try one of:

  - `vssadmin add shadowstorage /for=D: /on=D: /maxsize=100GB` *(Windows Server only)*

    - alternatively for non-server Windows editions try `vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=D: /on=D: /maxsize=10%` that will add shadow storage if it does not exist and thus is comparable to `vssadmin add`
  - `wmic shadowstorage call create Volume=D:\ DiffVolume=D:\ MaxSpace=20`

    - if this command returns `ReturnValue = 10` (which is [Unknown error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389392(v=vs.85).aspx)) workaround follows
  - `wmic shadowcopy call create Volume=D:\`

    - creating shadow copy on disk without shadow storage will create one automatically
    - you can resize the shadow storage with `vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=D: /on=D: /maxsize=10%`

**1.2 List shadow storages**

- make sure the shadow storage is there and configured using one of:

  - `vssadmin list shadowstorage`
  - `wmic shadowstorage list`

---

## 2 Create shadow copy

**2.1 Create shadow copy**

- you want to use scheduled system protection feature, but for now just take a snapshot manually:

  - `wmic shadowcopy call create Volume=D:\`

**2.2 List shadow copies**

- verify the snapshot was created:

  - `vssadmin list shadows /for=D:`

---

## 3 Mount shadow copy

- since you are using Storage Spaces, you won't see snapshots in `Previous versions` tab in disk/file properties
- but the snapshots exists and can be mounted as a folder
- this shortage apply for both NTFS and ReFS Storage Spaces
- to mount a snapshot you will need shadow ID, shadow path and temporary folder

**3.1 Get shadow copy ID**

- `vssadmin list shadows /for=D:`

  - look for something like this `Shadow Copy ID: {5cc29315-0379-415e-8496-69923618e3de}`

**3.2 Get shadow copy path**

- `wmic shadowcopy where "ID='{5cc29315-0379-415e-8496-69923618e3de}'" get DeviceObject`
- or `vssadmin list shadows /for=D:`

  - look for `Shadow Copy Volume: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy624`

**3.3 Mount shadow copy as folder**

- `mklink /j %tmp%\shadow \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy624\`

  - note the extra `\` at the end
  - the shadow copy is now available in `%tmp%\shadow`

Comment: This was successfully tested on [Windows 10 Pro v1607 b14393](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Rings) on [ReFS 1.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReFS#Version_history_and_compatibility) formatted 3 disk Storage Space in two-way mirror configuration with integrity streams enabled.

Comment: Also tested on [Windows 10 Pro for Workstations v1709 b16299](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Rings) with [ReFS 3.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReFS#Version_history_and_compatibility).

Comment: @peter thanks. It got bit long, but there are some useful bits. The tldr for you would be just this: `vssadmin resize shadowstorage /for=D: /on=D: /maxsize=10%`.